# How to create a separate class for a component in react native and use it as a common class?

Tags: react-native

Hi I am learning react native. I am using Modal component of react native. I need to use the same across multiple times in app. Here the code
Now I am trying to call the function
{this.createModal(dataForMaritalStatus)}
instead of

```
/* <Modal visible={this.state.isModalVisible}
                        onRequestClose={() => {
                            this.setState({ isModalVisible: false })
                        }}
                        animationType="fade"
                        transparent={true}
                    >
                        <View style={styles.modalContainer}>


                            <ScrollView
                                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
                            >
                                {dataForMaritalStatus === null ? <Text style={styles.nodata}>No data Found </Text> : dataForMaritalStatus.map((status, id) => (
                                    <View key={id}>
                                        <TouchableOpacity

                                            style={styles.opacity}
                                            onPress={() => {
                                                this._toggleModal()
                                            }}>
                                            <Text style={styles.taskList}>{status.value}</Text>
                                        </TouchableOpacity>
                                    </View>
                                ))}

                            </ScrollView>
                        </View>
                    </Modal>
*/
```

So how to make a common class for this component and pass different arrays of data and use it in render method ? The data is going to be different for different purposes and I need to maintain different states for different purposes.

Edit : I have written a method for it,but it calls the function but it does not render the modal, do I need to render it ?

```
    createModal = (data) => {

<Modal visible={this.state.isModalVisible}
                        onRequestClose={() => {
                            this.setState({ isModalVisible: false })
                        }}
                        animationType="fade"
                        transparent={true}
                    >
                        <View style={styles.modalContainer}>


                            <ScrollView
                                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
                            >
                                {data === null ? <Text style={styles.nodata}>No data Found </Text> : data.map((status, id) => (
                                    <View key={id}>
                                        <TouchableOpacity

                                            style={styles.opacity}
                                            onPress={() => {
                                                this._toggleModal()
                                            }}>
                                            <Text style={styles.taskList}>{status.value}</Text>
                                        </TouchableOpacity>
                                    </View>
                                ))}

                            </ScrollView>
                        </View>
                    </Modal>
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Create a separate file `customModalComponent.js`, and pass in the array data through props. Change your Modal component a little bit, use `this.props.dataForMaritalStatus` for `dataForMaritalStatus`..

```js
<ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}>
  {this.props.dataForMaritalStatus === null ? <Text style={styles.nodata}>No data Found </Text> 
    : this.props.dataForMaritalStatus.map((status, id) => (

      ...
  )}
</ScrollView>
```

and then on any other file, `import CustomModal from './customModalComponent'` and use it this way,

```js
<CustomModal dataForMaritalStatus={yourArrayOfData}/>
```

**Solution 2**

If you are just using it in the same file, create a function instead

```js
class myClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.createModal = this.createModal.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }

  createModal(dataForMaritalStatus) {
    return (
      //Insert your Modal code here
      ...
    )
  }
}
```

and use it this way in your render,

```js
render() {
  <View>
    ...
    { 
      this.createModal(yourArrayOfData)
    }
    ...
  </View>
}
```

Comment: Hi I have created this function at the bottom of the file but I am not able to use this function.it says not a function

Comment: Hey, did you create the function inside your component class? I have updated my answer above, you can check again. Include `this.createModal = this.createModal.bind(this);` in your `constructor` too if the function needs to access `this.props` or `this.state`

Comment: No I was trying to use it in same class, without creating different component class. I mean myClass which extends component I am trying to use it in that.

Comment: Ok, that means the function needs to be created inside your `myClass` component. Inside the whole `class myClass extends Component` curly bracket. Does this helps you? :)

Comment: Check my latest update again too, you need to remove the `function` keyword I included earlier

Comment: It works with => operator,but now when I am trying to call it exactly from the place where I had written modal earlier {this.createModal(dataForMaritalStatus)}; it calls the function but does not open the modal, it show alert.

Comment: Hmm, I cant tell what is causing this error..mind sharing your updated code again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189169/discussion-between-pritish-and-wicky).

Answer (score 2):

Create a separate component for Model

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View, Modal, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, Text } from "react-native";

export default class CustomModel extends Component {
  render() {
    const { dataForMaritalStatus } = this.props;
    return (
      <Modal
        visible={this.state.isModalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          this.setState({ isModalVisible: false });
        }}
        animationType="fade"
        transparent={true}
      >
        <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
          <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}>
            {dataForMaritalStatus === null ? (
              <Text style={styles.nodata}>No data Found </Text>
            ) : (
              dataForMaritalStatus.map((status, id) => (
                <View key={id}>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.opacity}
                    onPress={() => {
                      this._toggleModal();
                    }}
                  >
                    <Text style={styles.taskList}>{status.value}</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              ))
            )}
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

**don't forget to export that component.**

Now import that component in the file where you want to use that

```
import Model from "./CustomModel";
```

and use it this way

```
<CustomModel dataForMaritalStatus=[] />
```

you can pass data using props like a do above.

you can learn more about props here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/props

Comment: but how do I pass different arrays, and states to it and use it as the data is not going to be same ?

Answer (score 2):

create new component in one folder.

app -> CommonModal.js

**CommonModal.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Modal, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default class CommonModal extends Component{
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
}

render(){
return(
<Modal visible={this.state.isModalVisible}
                    onRequestClose={() => {
                        this.setState({ isModalVisible: false })
                    }}
                    animationType="fade"
                    transparent={true}
                >
                    <View style={styles.modalContainer}>


                        <ScrollView
                            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
                        >
                            {this.props.dataForMaritalStatus === null ? <Text style={styles.nodata}>No data Found </Text> : this.props.dataForMaritalStatus.map((status, id) => (
                                <View key={id}>
                                    <TouchableOpacity

                                        style={styles.opacity}
                                        onPress={() => {
                                            this._toggleModal()
                                        }}>
                                        <Text style={styles.taskList}>{status.value}</Text>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                </View>
                            ))}

                        </ScrollView>
                    </View>
                </Modal>
)
}
```

*note: i have used this.props.dataForMaritalStatus*

And then use it wherever you need the component

app -> Second.js

**Second.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import CommonModal from './CommonModal';

export default class Second extends Component{
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state={
dataForMaritalStatus:['val1','val2']
}
}
render(){
return(<View style={{flex:1}}>
<CommonModal dataForMaritalStatus={this.state.dataForMaritalStatus}/>
</View>)}
}
```